# jQuery Example: How to shorten this code efficiently?

Tags: javascript, jquery

Following example is valid and works properly, but it is too long and the same things are repeated often. (I've to do it on this way, because I may not use multiple-upload attribute - HTML5 -). User should be able to upload several files (up to 5) and each time via a new input-file-element. They should only appeare, if necessary.

This is the HTML-Part:

```
<input type="file" id="image1" class="fileImage">
    <button class="cShow" id="show_i2">+1</button><br/>

<input type="file" id="image2" class="fileImage">
    <button class="cShow" id="show_i3">+1</button>
        <button class="cDel" id="del_i2">Delete</button><br/>

<input type="file" id="image3" class="fileImage">
    <button class="cShow" id="show_i4">+1</button>
        <button class="cDel" id="del_i3">Delete</button><br/>

<input type="file" id="image4" class="fileImage">
    <button class="cShow" id="show_i5">+1</button>
        <button class="cDel" id="del_i4">Delete</button><br/>

<input type="file" id="image5" class="fileImage">
    <button class="cDel" id="del_i5">Delete</button><br/>
```

This is jQuery-Part:

```
$('#show_i2').click(function(event) {
    $('#image2, #show_i3, #del_i2').show();
    $('#show_i2').hide();
    event.preventDefault();
});

$('#show_i3').click(function(event) {
    $('#image3, #del_i3, #show_i4').show();
    $('#show_i3, #del_i2').hide();

    event.preventDefault();
});

$('#show_i4').click(function(event) {
    $('#image4, #del_i4, #show_i5').show();
    $('#show_i4, #del_i3').hide();

    event.preventDefault();
});

$('#show_i5').click(function(event) {
    $('#image5, #del_i5').show();
    $('#show_i5, #del_i4').hide();
    event.preventDefault();
});


$('#del_i2').click(function(event) {
    $('#image2, #del_i2, #show_i3').hide();
    $('#show_i2').show();
    event.preventDefault();

});

$('#del_i3').click(function(event) {
    $('#image3, #del_i3, #show_i4').hide();
    $('#show_i3, #del_i2').show();
    event.preventDefault();
});

$('#del_i4').click(function(event) {
    $('#image4, #del_i4, #show_i5').hide();
    $('#show_i4, #del_i3').show();
    event.preventDefault();
});

$('#del_i5').click(function(event) {
    $('#image5, #del_i5').hide();
    $('#show_i5, #del_i4').show();
    event.preventDefault();
});
```

How can I shorten this?

Comment: it would help if you _described_ the desired behaviour rather than expecting us to grok your existing code completely first

Comment: I was trying to describe more details but JoDev has already answered below..

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use something like this :  (for show part)

```
$('[id^="show_i"]').click(function(event) {
    var index = $(this).attr(id).replace('show_i', '').parseInt();
    $('#image'+index+', #del_i'+index+', #show_i'+(index+1)).show();
    $('#show_i'+index+', #del_i'+(index-1)).hide();

    event.preventDefault();
});
```

I use the `begin with` selector of [jQuery](http://api.jquery.com/attribute-starts-with-selector/)

Use this idea for the delete part

```
$('[id^="del_i"]').click(function(event) {
    var index = $(this).attr(id).replace('del_i', '').parseInt();
    $('#image'+index+', #del_i'+index+', #show_i'+(index+1)).hide();
    $('#show_i'+index).show();
    event.preventDefault();

});
```

Comment: Nice solution, take my +1! =)

Comment: only one small flaw: SyntaxError: missing ) after argument list ->
$('[id^="del_i"]').click(function(event) {

Comment: Yes, `);` was missing in the first block!